# Tomcat application as a client to another server using TLSv1.2

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, tomcat7, tls1.2

We have a Tomcat based Infra monitoring application which will connect to other servers and monitor / alert etc.

However , some of our servers are using TLSv1.2 only and seems that the monitoring application is only using the TLSv1 to connect which is having a slight issue.

We are currently doing a workaround by using http port to mornitor but for long term we would like to use the TLSv1.2.

Is there a way to force Tomcat to connect to other applications via TLSv1.2 only?

Thanks

Using Tomcat 7 and Java 1.7.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the SunJSSEProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) says:

> Although SunJSSE in the Java SE 7 release supports TLS 1.1 and TLS
>   1.2, neither version is enabled by default for client connections. Some servers do not implement forward compatibility correctly and
>   refuse to talk to TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 clients. For interoperability,
>   SunJSSE does not enable TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 by default for client
>   connections.

So TLS 1.2 is there, it just isn't enabled. To enable it add something like

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

to the startup-parameters of your tomcat. Then it should be able to speak TLS 1.2 as well as TLS 1.1. If you need any older protocols you can also add them as described in the linked documentation.

Comment: Tried adding in setEnv.bat        :                                                                 set JAVA_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.2" -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2"